# U-Boot - multiple same output formats in linker scripts for ARM

Tags: arm, u-boot, linker-scripts

I'm currently investigating the `U-Boot` source tree, because I want add support for a specific ARM architecture for the purpose of education.

Also investigated the linker scripts for ARM, but there is something what I currently don't understand:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm", "elf32-littlearm")
```

*Source:*
[GitHub: U-Boot: arch/arm/cpu/u-boot-spl.lds](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/arch/arm/cpu/u-boot-spl.lds)
[GitHub: U-Boot: arch/arm/cpu/u-boot.lds](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/arch/arm/cpu/u-boot.lds)

What is the meaning, when multiple output formats with the same format are defined in a linker script? Can somebody explain this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binutil manpages are available at https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Format-Commands.html

The first argument is the default output format the second one is for a user explicitly asking for big-endian with -EB passed to ld, the third for a user explicitly asking for low-endian with -EL.

If all are the same, using a single parameter for OUTPUT_FORMAT should have the same effect.